# 2 domains 1 host package

Tags: web-hosting, domains, dns, windows

I have a windows web hosting package.
I have 2 different domain names.

Can i point my first domain to the the hosting package and then run BlogEngine.NET and then point the second domain to the hosting package running NopCommerce cart?

www.domain1.co.uk (blog) 
www.domain2.co.uk (e-commerce cart)

In IIS i would just create a new application within the site and create the bindings for domain2. But does this work for web hosting packages from 123-reg.co.uk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can, why not? You only need to make sure that your current plan support 2 domains or not. Then, please ask your current provider to install it for you. Good luck. :)

Comment: Yes it says unlimited domains so i can point to different websites.. :)